# How to leave message if no one answers twilio

Tags: java, sdk, twilio

I am able call my number and successfully see the XML post in the logs I have running but at the conclusion of the call I don't have any voicemails in my box. Any ideas on what else I am missing?

```
String answeredBy = req.getParameter("AnsweredBy");

TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
try {
    if (answeredBy.equalsIgnoreCase("machine")) {
        twiml.append(new Say("Message I want to leave."));
    }
}

req.setAttribute("xml", twiml.toXML());
```

The xml attribute is printed on the JSP page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say>Message I want to leave.</Say>
</Response>
```

I see the logs firing off the XML at the same time of me receiving the call but I receive no voicemail. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sending the `ifMachine` parameter when you initiate the call?

Comment: IfMachine is set to continue.